# Safari video not working but all browser work autoplay. multiple video play one by one

Tags: javascript, css, html

**html5 video safari autoplay not working ?????????
my code for multiple video play one by one work good but it's not working safari browser there is any way to start autoplay in safari also please help me this query. Any way to use and work fine in safari browser.
There is any other way to work to use it.
thanks
the code is only HTML and js CSS that I'm using hear to create an id in and use to play video in the browser.
**

```
    <div class="video-container " id="video_auto_play">
<video autoplay="autoplay" controls muted id="home_videoPlayer" style="object-fit: initial;" >
  <source id="home_videoPlayer" style="object-fit: initial;"  type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<script> 
    document.getElementById('home_videoPlayer').play(); 
</script>
</div>


<script>
var videoSource = new Array();


videoSource[0] = 'a1.mp4';
videoSource[1] = 'a2.mp4';
videoSource[2] = 'a3.mp4';
videoSource[3] = 'a4.mp4';

var i = 0; // define i
var videoCount = videoSource.length;

function videoPlay(videoNum) {
    document.getElementById("home_videoPlayer").setAttribute("src", videoSource[videoNum]);
    document.getElementById("home_videoPlayer").play();
    document.getElementById("home_videoPlayer").play();
}
document.getElementById('home_videoPlayer').addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);
videoPlay(0); // play the video

function myHandler() {
    i++;
    if (i == (videoCount - 0)) {
        i = 0;
        videoPlay(i);
    } else {
        videoPlay(i);
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine. Have you checked Safari > Settings for This Website in the menu bar?

[image]

```js
   document.getElementById('home_videoPlayer').play(); 


var videoSource = new Array();


videoSource[0] = 'https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4';
videoSource[1] = 'https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4';
videoSource[2] = 'https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4';
videoSource[3] = 'https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4';

var i = 0; // define i
var videoCount = videoSource.length;

function videoPlay(videoNum) {
    document.getElementById("home_videoPlayer").setAttribute("src", videoSource[videoNum]);
    document.getElementById("home_videoPlayer").play();
    document.getElementById("home_videoPlayer").play();
}
document.getElementById('home_videoPlayer').addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);
videoPlay(0); // play the video

function myHandler() {
    i++;
    if (i == (videoCount - 0)) {
        i = 0;
        videoPlay(i);
    } else {
        videoPlay(i);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container " id="video_auto_play">
<video autoplay="autoplay" controls muted id="home_videoPlayer" style="object-fit: initial;" >
  <source id="home_videoPlayer" style="object-fit: initial;"  type="video/mp4" />
</video>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks your replay but that's not right way i can't go my client and custmor Iphone browser and change the settings every time.if any way of code that can change it or any mistks in code auto play work in every safari browser.